# How to return all data in database as Json?

Tags: python, json, django, database, rest

How to return all data in database as Json?
Models.py:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
    Hero_id = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='Hero_id')
    race = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    class_= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Views.py:

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ['Hero_id', 'race', 'age', 'class_']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'race': {
                    'required': False,
                    'allow_null':True
                 },
                'age': {
                    'required': False,
                    'allow_null':True
                 },
                'class_': {
                    'required': False,
                    'allow_null':True
                 }
            }
def HHH():
    h=Hero.objects.all()
    serializer= HeroSerializer(h)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

But it returns me an error:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field Hero_id on serializer HeroSerializer. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the str instance. Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'Hero_id'.
Any ideas?

Comment: Update your question with your Hero model code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're serializing a bunch of instances you need to pass `many=True` to the serializer:

```
def HHH():
    h=Hero.objects.all()
    serializer= HeroSerializer(h, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Take a look at the examples provided by the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#writing-regular-django-views-using-our-serializer). Also, field name `class_` is not valid at least in Django 2.x and you'll get the error:

```
ERRORS:
core.Hero.class_: (fields.E001) Field names must not end with an underscore.
```

---

To render into the template (assumed it's configured properly) you could use `render` function, e.g.

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def HHH():
    heros = Hero.objects.all()
    serializer = HeroSerializer(heros, many=True)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'heros': serializer.data})
```

*index.html*

```
{% for hero in heros %}
    <p>{{ hero.age }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It returns Ordered dict but I need simple dictionary. How to convert it?

Comment: You could use `dict` constructor to convert to vanilla `dict`, e.g. `dict(ordered_dict)`, but I don't know why this is needed.

Comment: Now it returns: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required. In other functions i need to pass Json in html form: `return render(request, "1.html", {"Hero":serializer.data})`

Comment: `json.dumps(serializer.data)`

Comment: Thank you! But one last question. How can I pass it in html as i mentioned above?

Comment: @Denzel Most likely call your endpoint on the client-side with some javascript... Actually this question is too broad and depends on a particular case.

Comment: Well... unfortunately I need to do it on server side

Comment: I found json.dumps() and it converts ordered dictionaries to normal.